# Python - How to print a specific text

Tags: python, printing, split, xmpp

```
def handler_users_answ(coze, res, type, source):
    if res:
        if res.getType() == 'result':
            aa=res.getQueryChildren()
            if aa:
                print 'workz1'
                for x in aa:
                    m=x.getAttr('jid')
                    if m:
                        print m
```

so this code returns me the values like this:

```
roomname@domain.com/nickname1
roomname@domain.com/nickname2
```

and so on, but i want it to print the value after the '/' only.
like:

```
nickname1
nickname2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you use getter/setter methods? That's very unpythonic. If you need getter/setter logic, use properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`rpartition`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) to get the part after the last `\` in the string.

Comment: I just learned rpartition, always used rsplit(1)[1] for this, nice to know, +1, thanks.

Comment: @utdemir: I think the difference is mostly one of style, although a quick `timeit` suggests that in certain cases `rpartition` is a bit faster.

Comment: rpartition is incorrect here, because this is a valid JID: `foo@example.com/bar/baz`, and the resource portion is `bar/baz`, not `baz`.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 'roomname@domain.com/nickname1'

b=a.split('/');
c=b[1];
```

Comment: This also fails on `roomname@domain.com/nickname1/foo`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rsplit](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) which will do the splitting form the right:

```
a = 'roomname@domain.com/nickname1'
try:
    print a.rsplit('/')[1][1]
except IndexError:
    print "No username was found"
```

I think that this is efficient and readable. If you really need it to be fast you can use [rfind](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind):

```
a = 'roomname@domain.com/nickname1'
index = a.rfind('/')
if index != -1:
    print a[index+1:]
else:
    print "No username was found"
```

Comment: Both of these fail on `roomname@domain.com/nickname1/foo`.

Comment: Of course it fails. The problem was about roomname@domain.com/nickname1 not roomname@domain.com/nickname1/foo

Comment: Right.  The question was poorly worded.  The *intent* of the question was "how do I parse an RFC 6122 Jabber ID?".

Answer (score 1):

To fully parse and validate the JID correctly, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514342/validating-an-xmpp-jid-with-python/3519699#3519699).  There's a bunch of odd little edge cases that you might not expect.