# Concatenating two range function results

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, concatenation

Does range function allows concatenation ? Like i want to make a `range(30)` & concatenate it with `range(2000, 5002)`.  So my concatenated range will be `0, 1, 2, ... 29, 2000, 2001,  ... 5001`

Code like this does not work on my latest python (ver: 3.3.0)

```
range(30) + range(2000, 5002)
```

Comment: the version of my python is  version 3.3.0 .. i have also updated in my question

Comment: What do you want to get as a result (as in, what type of data - a plain list, a generator, something else)? What do you want to do with the result?

Answer (score 101):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) for this:

```
from itertools import chain
concatenated = chain(range(30), range(2000, 5002))
for i in concatenated:
     ...
```

It works for arbitrary iterables. Note that there's a difference in behavior of [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) between Python 2 and 3 that you should know about: in Python 2 [`range`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) returns a list, and in Python3 an iterator, which is memory-efficient, but not always desirable.

Lists can be concatenated with `+`, iterators cannot.

Comment: For me, this has to be one of the ugliest bits of Python. For such a basic task to have external lib requirement for this is ridiculous...

Comment: @amos-folarin I tend to agree, that's why i was impressed to find [coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), a python-like language with all functional tools readily available as syntactic sugar.

Comment: Beware: you cannot save a chain to use a second time. You get to iterate over it once. If you try again, you get nothing. This is in stark contrast to how a range works.

Answer (score 60):

I like the most simple solutions that are possible (including efficiency). It is not always clear whether the solution is such. Anyway, the `range()` in Python 3 is a generator. You can wrap it to any construct that does iteration. The `list()` is capable of construction of a list value from any iterable. The `+` operator for lists does concatenation. I am using smaller values in the example:

```
>>> list(range(5))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(range(10, 20))
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> list(range(5)) + list(range(10,20))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

This is what `range(5) + range(10, 20)` exactly did in Python 2.5 -- because `range()` returned a list.

In Python 3, it is only useful if you really want to construct the list. Otherwise, I recommend the [Lev Levitsky's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14099894/1346705) solution with [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain). The documentation also shows the very straightforward implementation:

```
def chain(*iterables):
    # chain('ABC', 'DEF') --> A B C D E F
    for it in iterables:
        for element in it:
            yield element
```

The solution by [Inbar Rose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14100069/1346705) is fine and functionally equivalent. Anyway, my +1 goes to Lev Levitsky and to his argument about using the standard libraries. From *The Zen of Python*...

> In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.

```
#!python3
import timeit
number = 10000

t = timeit.timeit('''\
for i in itertools.chain(range(30), range(2000, 5002)):
    pass
''',
'import itertools', number=number)
print('itertools:', t/number * 1000000, 'microsec/one execution')

t = timeit.timeit('''\
for x in (i for j in (range(30), range(2000, 5002)) for i in j):
    pass
''', number=number)
print('generator expression:', t/number * 1000000, 'microsec/one execution')
```

In my opinion, the `itertools.chain` is more readable. But what really is important...

```
itertools: 264.4522138986938 microsec/one execution
generator expression: 785.3081048010291 microsec/one execution
```

... it is about 3 times faster.

Comment: this is great, i will admit defeat by efficiently built standard library modules. but your timing is strange, on my machine after numerous tests, i found that my solution is only about 1.8 times slower, as opposed to 3 times slower. but it is still slower.

Comment: It is definitely hardware dependent and could be also OS dependent. I did use my rather obsolete computer with AMD Athlon 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 3800+ at 2.01 GHz, with 3 GB of memory. The OS is Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit (both processor and memory score is only 4,9 -- http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-is-the-Windows-Experience-Index). I am not sure about the Python implementation. Say, you may have more processor cores.

Answer (score 50):

### python >= 3.5

You can use iterable unpacking in lists (see PEP 448: [Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)).

If you need a list,

```
[*range(2, 5), *range(3, 7)]
# [2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This preserves order and does not remove duplicates. Or, you might want a tuple,

```
(*range(2, 5), *range(3, 7))
# (2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

... or a set,

```
# note that this drops duplicates
{*range(2, 5), *range(3, 7)}
# {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

It also happens to be faster than calling `itertools.chain`.

```
from itertools import chain

%timeit list(chain(range(10000), range(5000, 20000)))
%timeit [*range(10000), *range(5000, 20000)]

738 µs ± 10.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
665 µs ± 13.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The benefit of `chain`, however, is that you can pass an arbitrary list of ranges.

```
ranges = [range(2, 5), range(3, 7), ...]
flat = list(chain.from_iterable(ranges))
```

OTOH, unpacking generalisations haven't been "generalised" to arbitrary sequences, so you will still need to unpack the individual ranges yourself.

Comment: Thanks -- this is much nicer, cleaner than the suggested answer.

Answer (score 40):

Can be done using [list-comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
>>> [i for j in (range(10), range(15, 20)) for i in j]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Works for your request, but it is a long answer so I will not post it here.

note: can be made into a generator for increased performance:

```
for x in (i for j in (range(30), range(2000, 5002)) for i in j):
    # code
```

or even into a generator variable.

```
gen = (i for j in (range(30), range(2000, 5002)) for i in j)
for x in gen:
    # code
```

Comment: @mkind thanks, i hate dependencies, people always jump and answer with tons of imports and libraries, but they are not always available, and they often times do the same thing that normal code does, only wrapped in a package, its not magic. :)

Comment: I don't think that _not using standard libraries_ is a virtue on its own, but this is a nice answer.

Comment: @inbar, you're right. two additional advantage are that you know what the code does and that you are learning something about the problem.

Comment: @LevLevitsky /mkind : the code for chain: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain is exactly what my list-comprehension/generator does, only you dont need to import anything, and you can see it right in front of you/modify it if you need with conditions etc...

Comment: @mkind and Inbar Rose: Hating dependencies may be OK, but the `itertools` module is the standard one. Because of its more efficient implementation, the solution with `itertools.chain` is about 3 times faster -- see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14101734/1346705. The moral is: *"Never say never!"*

Comment: @pepr i totally agree. although, i try to use as less deps as possible.

Comment: For a python novice like me this took a couple of time to understand; the `for` loop inheritance looks some kind of non-obvious. Please consider to add an additional explanation like [this](https://pastebin.com/sZkea74F) one I'd just posted as an example.

Answer (score 9):

With the help of the extend method, we can concatenate two lists.

```
>>> a = list(range(1,10))
>>> a.extend(range(100,105))
>>> a  
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104]
```

Comment: This is for Python 2, the OP uses Python 3.

Comment: Extend is not a keyword, it is a method on Python lists.

Answer (score 4):

`range()` in Python 2.x returns a list:

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

`xrange()` in Python 2.x returns an iterator:

```
>>> xrange(10)
xrange(10)
```

And in Python 3 `range()` also returns an iterator:

```
>>> r = range(10)
>>> iterator = r.__iter__()
>>> iterator.__next__()
0
>>> iterator.__next__()
1
>>> iterator.__next__()
2
```

So it is clear that you can not concatenate iterators other by using `chain()` as the other guy pointed out.

Comment: your answer is helpful, but does not provide a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list function around range function to make a list
LIKE THIS

```
list(range(3,7))+list(range(2,9))
```

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question because I was trying to concatenate an unknown number of ranges, that might overlap, and didn't want repeated values in the final iterator. My solution was to use `set` and the [`union`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set.union) operator like so:

```
range1 = range(1,4)
range2 = range(2,6)
concatenated = set.union(set(range1), set(range2)
for i in concatenated:
    print(i)
```

Comment: This will not maintain order unless python3.7, this will also not allow for partial overlaps in ranges (ie, allow for duplicates).

Comment: @cs95 Order is not maintained even in Python-3.7 -- it' the `dict` that keeps the order, not the `set`, which till sort them according to value hashes.