# adding ranges in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, addition

I have the following code:

```
for inc in range(0, ninc+1)+range(ninc-1,-1,-1):
```

But it gives me such an error:

```
for inc in range(0, ninc+1)+range(ninc-1,-1,-1):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'range'
```

I am using Python 3.3.2. Any suggestions?

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting the result to be, and why?

Answer (score 5):

`range` objects aren't lists, so you can't add them together. You can, however, chain the two iterables:

```
import itertools

for inc in itertools.chain(range(0, ninc + 1), range(ninc - 1, -1, -1)):
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.x's [`range`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) doesn't return a list, but a `range` object. So, we have to create a list out of that object like this

```
rlist = list(range(0, ninc+1))
for inc in rlist + rlist[-2::-1]:
```

Comment: The second list is the reversal of the first, so you'll build 2 lists,  when one will be enogh

Comment: @volcano You are absolutely correct :) Please check my updated answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
myIterator = chain(range(0, ninc + 1), range(ninc - 1, -1, -1))
for x in myIterator:
..
```

or something similar.

Found from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14099894/3093524

Answer (score 0):

Maybe range.extend (python2 only)

```
range_1 = range(2)
range_2 = range(3)
range_1.extend(range_2)

print(range_1)
[0, 1, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: This won't work in Python 3; there is no `range.extend`, there's only `list.extend`, and in Python 3 `range` doesn't return a `list`.