# Two separate for-loops in list comprehension

Tags: python

Is it possible two have to separate for loop in a single comprehension? Something like

```py
A = [i * 2 in range(5, 10), j + 2 for j in range(5) ]
# To get A = [10, 12, 14, 16, 19, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

The closest that comes to what I need is

```
A = [*[i * 2 for i in range(5, 10)], *[j + 2 for j in range(5)]]
```

Is there a better (more python-ic) way of doing this?

Comment: `from itertools import chain; [i for i in chain(range(5, 10), range(5))]`? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099872

Comment: @Andrew Allen Why iterate through the iterable? `from itertools import chain; A = list(chain(range(5, 10), range(5)))`

Comment: @VigneshBayariR.  was assuming OP was going to do something with the `i`

Comment: @AndrewAllen this would work when I want to process both loops in the same manner, I've updated my question for more clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add both lists:

```
A = [i * 2 for i in range(5, 10)] + [j + 2 for j in range(5) ]
```