# For loop between two different intervals

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, range

This is 100% a dumb question but I couldn't find the answer. Would i be able to do a for loop between two different intervals?

Take for example:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i in range(0,5) and range(7,9):
    print(array[i])
```

and it would output:
1,2,3,4,5,8,9

Edit:
As Adam.Er8 pointed out,
[itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), would be the cleaner solutions.

Another solution I found while experimenting was without the itertools would be:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
needrange = [[1,3],[5,7],[8,9]]
for j in range(0,len(needrange)):
    for i in range(needrange[j][0],needrange[j][1]):
        print(array[i])
```

This solution isn't clean but it does do the job if you aren't looking to import.

Credit to cs95 from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099872/concatenating-two-range-function-results), who wrote:

```
ranges = [range(2, 5), range(3, 7), ...]
flat = list(chain.from_iterable(ranges))
```

Notes found while writing this response):

I'm pretty sure range(n,m) from cs95 answer just returns a list as well, whereas I just created a list initially. So very similar

The function from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain),looks very similar logic wise, but I just found my solution easier to read.

Comment: @jerin That's right. *"The expression `x and y` first evaluates x; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned."* https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.chain(range(0,5), range(7,9))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty, but you can do

```
for i in list(range(0,5)) + list(range(7,9)):
    print(array[i])
```

You can add lists together; just not ranges.

Well, that's not entirely true, using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain
for i in chain(range(0,5), range(7,9)):
    print(array[i])
```

It doesn't really add them together; it just "chains" any iterable, including a range object.

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i in [*range(0,5), *range(7,9)]:
    print(array[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean "how do I create an union between 2 different ranges?", in which case:

```py
for i in list(range(0, 5)) + list(range(7, 9)):
    # ...
```

Although, a warning: Doing it this way will expand the range into a list, putting every element in it in its own entry. Doing this with a large range may cause memory issues